# What is difference between setting number of epochs vs calling it repeatedly in a for loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

import numpy as np
"""
"""
from numpy.random import seed
seed(10)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
import tensorflow as tf
set_random_seed(1)
import os
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
from keras import backend as K
K.set_session(sess)
"""

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout,CuDNNGRU,CuDNNLSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back):
        dataX.append(dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0])
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)


dataset = np.cos(np.arange(1000)*(20*np.pi/1000))[:,None]
plt.plot(dataset)
plt.show()

look_back = 30
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]

trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[1], 1))
testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], testX.shape[1], 1))

batch_size = 1
model = Sequential()
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(16, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1),  stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(16, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1),  stateful=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(16,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()


trainScore = model.evaluate(trainX, trainY, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
print('Train Score: ', trainScore)
testScore = model.evaluate(testX[:252], testY[:252], batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
print('Test Score: ', testScore)

look_ahead = 250
trainPredict = [np.vstack([trainX[-1][1:], trainY[-1]])]
predictions = np.zeros((look_ahead,1))
for i in range(look_ahead):
    prediction = model.predict(np.array([trainPredict[-1]]), batch_size=batch_size)
    predictions[i] = prediction
    trainPredict.append(np.vstack([trainPredict[-1][1:],prediction]))


plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
# plt.plot(np.arange(len(trainX)),np.squeeze(trainX))
# plt.plot(np.arange(200),scaler.inverse_transform(np.squeeze(trainPredict)[:,None][1:]))
# plt.plot(np.arange(200),scaler.inverse_transform(np.squeeze(testY)[:,None][:200]),'r')
plt.plot(np.arange(look_ahead),predictions,'r',label="prediction")
plt.plot(np.arange(look_ahead),dataset[train_size:(train_size+look_ahead)],label="test function")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This code is based on this guys example here:

https://github.com/sachinruk/PyData_Keras_Talk/blob/master/cosine_LSTM.ipynb

Instead of setting the number of epochs he is using a for loop. Can you just set epochs in the fit command?

Secondly without setting a seed my results between runs vary wildly. I understand you need to set a seed to get reproducible results. However should results vary this much.  In one case I am getting something that looks like a sinewave. Sometimes I end up with a straight line. Sometimes I end with a sine wave with the wrong frequency. Is this much variability normal?

Since in this case we are using the LSTM to predict multiple points the future I understand that we can have compounding errors. I am wondering if the was the fit is being called is maybe causing that. I have tried both methods and they seem to yield similar results. I am kind of lost on why this is happening.

Here is an example of the various outputs I got:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKgx0.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences between running single epochs in a for loop vs specifying multipe epochs in the fit.

For ex: the learning rate decay usually works / gets modified after each epoch.

Following post has more specifics on this

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26112/decay-parameter-in-keras-optimizers?rq=1